# MS SQL 2008 running query with known field that have blanks but does not return those records

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a query to get the results from two tables.  Rather that have 5 records per entry # or (DOC#) I have had multiple inner joins on the same table to get multiple results on one record per entry.

BASIC QUERY RESULTS

```
Date    GL# AccountName AccountDesc Amount          Doc#    FieldG
00:00.0 51010   Account1    Description1    -3230.77    494634  TECH
00:00.0 51010   Account1    Description1    -3230.77    494634  220
00:00.0 51010   Account1    Description1    -3230.77    494634  SGA
00:00.0 51010   Account1    Description1    -3230.77    494634  TX
00:00.0 51010   Account1    Description1    -3230.77    494634
```

WITH MULTIPLE INNER JOINS ON SAME TABLE

```
Date    GL# AccountName AccountDesc Amount   Doc#    
00:00.0 51010   Account1    Description1    -3230.77 494634 TECH 220 SGA TX
```

QUERY I AM USING

```
SELECT 
GLE.Date
,GLE.GL# 
,GLE.AccountName
,GLE.AccountDesc
,GLE.Amount
,GLE.Doc#
,LED.FieldG
,LED2.FieldH
,LED3.FieldI
,LED4.FieldJ
,LED5.Unit 

FROM [Company, Inc$G_L Entry]  GLE
INNER JOIN [Company, Inc$Ledger Entry Dimension] LED
    ON GLE.[Doc#]=LED.[Doc#]
INNER JOIN [Company, Inc$Ledger Entry Dimension] LED2
    ON GLE.[Doc#]=LED2.[Doc#]
INNER JOIN [Company, Inc$Ledger Entry Dimension] LED3
    ON GLE.[Doc#]=LED3.[Doc#]
INNER JOIN [Company, Inc$Ledger Entry Dimension] LED4
    ON GLE.[Doc#]=LED4.[Doc#]
 JOIN [Company, Inc$Ledger Entry Dimension] LED5
    ON GLE.[Doc#]=LED5.[Doc#]



WHERE LED.Date Between '20120101' and '20130101'
AND GLE.[G_L Account No_]between '50000' and '59999'
AND GLE.GD1C between '0000' and '0999'
AND GLE.[Doc#]='494634' 
AND LED.[DC_1]='FieldG'
AND LED2.[DC_1]='FieldH'
AND LED3.[DC_1]='FieldI' 
AND LED4.[DC_1]='FieldJ'
AND LED5.[DC_1]='UNIT'
ORDER BY GLE.Date
```

I am specifically using a hard value for the DOC# so that I can test to limit my results.  I know I have a Unit field for this record and it is blank.  When I run the query, it does not return any results.  I know it is failing because I am using an INNER JOIN for the LED5 table, since it does not have a matching record.  All other fields have data as it is mandatory, so those don't fail.  As a novice, what can I change in this query to get the records that contain data and are blank too?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN first and also change WHERE clause to AND ISNULL(LED5.[DC_1],'UNIT')='UNIT'